what is username/password in ubuntu 22.04.5 live server x64
what is username/password in ubuntu 22.04.5 live server x64
itried ubuntu/ubuntu root/ubuntu UBUNTU/UBUNTU ROOT/ROOT
nothing is working tnx

Have you tried just hitting enter (ie. no password), as that works on most Desktop ISOs.  Do note the root user is disabled by default on most Ubuntu products

it is empty no password assigned to the live user and the username of the user is "ubuntu" without the curly braces
that is why you can install programs without entering password when you do sudo apt install <sth>
if you urgently need a password try to reset it by using sudo passwd ubuntu
